# Undefined Result in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, undefined

I created this function which should give me back 105; 6.5 and 110; 4.5 instead of this I receive `undefined: undefinedundefined: undefined`
Can anyone tell my what I have to do that I get the right result? I read something with asynchron, but I'm not really sure what I have to chance?!

Here is my function (in Meteor isClient)...

```
var d = 0;
var finalReturn = "";
while(distinctPlayer[d]) {
    var total = 0;
    Spieltag.find({SpielerID: distinctPlayer[d]}).map(function (doc) {
        total += doc.Note;
    });

    var finalName = 0;
    Spieltag.find({SpielerID: distinctPlayer[d]}).map(function (doc) {
        finalName = doc.SpielerID;
    });

    finalReturn += finalName[d] +": "+ total[d];
    d++;
}
return finalReturn;
```

And in the HTML, it looks like this

```
<p>
    <pre>{{otherHelperFunction}}</pre>
</p>
```

Comment: `total` and `finalName` are not arrays. they are single, stand-alone variables.

Comment: I guess you are using `.find()` and `.map()` mistakenly. `find`should receive a callback as first argument, instead you are sending an object. `map` does not return a value, thus does not map.

Answer (score 0):

try to use fetch() after find() and before map()

```
var d = 0;
var finalReturn = "";
while(distinctPlayer[d]) {
    var total = 0;
    Spieltag.find({SpielerID: distinctPlayer[d]}).fetch().map(function (doc) {
        total += doc.Note;
    });

    var finalName = 0;
    Spieltag.find({SpielerID: distinctPlayer[d]}).fetch().map(function (doc) {
        finalName = doc.SpielerID;
    });

    finalReturn += finalName[d] +": "+ total[d];
    d++;
}
return finalReturn;
```